# I want to sort the score in my json file from highest to lowest using java script

Tags: javascript, json

This is my current Json file

```
{
  "people": [
    {
      "name": "Person A",
      "score": 100
    },
    {
      "name": "Person B",
      "score": 101
    },
    {
      "name": "Person C",
      "score": 100000
    },
    {
      "name": "Person D",
      "score": 555
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried using this to sort the score but I've had no luck.

```
items.sort(function (a, b) {
return a.score - b.score;
});
```

When I run my code i get the error 
"SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'sort'"

If anyone has any ideas to help me out that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Using Javascript

Comment: What is items? How are you getting the json file.

Comment: I'm using an ajax get request to get my data.json and my "items" comes from

          var items = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

Comment: Use `var items = jQuery.parseJSON(data).people;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var items= {
  "people": [
    {
      "name": "Person A",
      "score": 100
    },
    {
      "name": "Person B",
      "score": 101
    },
    {
      "name": "Person C",
      "score": 100000
    },
    {
      "name": "Person D",
      "score": 555
    }
  ]
};

items.people.sort(function(a, b){
   return a.score - b.score;
});
console.log(items);
```

it works as expected!